# Extract a value from the list returned by $lookup in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have 2 collections in a mongo database.

```py
# Collaction 1 named C1
{
   _id: 1,
  a: 10
},
{
  _id: 2,
  a: 20
}
```

```py
# Collaction 2 named C2
{
   _id: 1,
  b: 500
},
{
  _id: 2,
  b: 600
}
```

I tried to join both using below `$lookup` query

```js
db.C1.aggregate(
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "C2",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "b"
    }
  }
]);
```

It returns an output collection that looks like this,

```py
{
  _id: 1,
  a: 10,
  b: [{_id: 1, b: 500}]
},
{
  _id: 2,
  a: 20,
  b: [{_id: 2, b: 600}]
}
```

join worked successfully, but I want only the value of ***b*** from collection 2 instead of whole document as a list,

```py
#Desired Output
{
  _id: 1,
  a: 10,
  b: 500
},
{
  _id: 2,
  a: 20,
  b: 600
}
```

How can we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Concise syntax](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#correlated-subqueries-using-concise-syntax).

Set a variable with `_id` in `let` field and use `pipeline` field to implement the desired stages on your `lookup` collection (c2).

I hope this code help you:

```js
db.C1.aggregate(
[
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "C2",
            "as": "b",
            "let": {
                "localId": "$_id"
            },
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "$expr": {
                            "$eq": [
                                "$_id",
                                "$$localId"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$project": {
                        "_id": false,
                        "b": true
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$limit": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "b": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$b",
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
);
```

Stage 3 on `lookup`'s pipeline is for fetch just first document (`$limit: 1`).

and Stage 2 on `aggregate` is for replace just `$b` value on `b` property.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! 

Comment: does this not end up as b: { b: "valueof b" } ?

Comment: For those who came here, you may want to add a `b: "$b.b"` in the final $project pipeline to extract the value